# Custom Calendar Carousel in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter

The default calendar carousel has no way to customize its cells. Is there any property or a library which can help to customise a Calendar carousel similar to the screen attached[image]
I am using the  https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/flutter_calendar_carousel/latest/

Comment: What you mean by customizing cell, its layout or something else

Comment: so the cells need 8 written n also an icon on top

Comment: yup. if I can give it a layout equivant in dart